# Как правильно реализовать TimerTask для обновления данных каждые 5 секунд?

Tags: java, android, adapter, таймер

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно реализовать TimerTask чтобы обновить данные (JSON) каждые 5 секунд и обновить пользовательский интерфейс. Мой код работает с ошибкой и пользовательский интерфейс не обновляется.
Мой код

loadData - вытаскиваю данные из бд.

```java
    void loadDB(){
        new GetAllVsiblePricesForUpdate(getContext(), new AsyncTaskCallback<List<Prices>>() {
            @Override
            public void handleResponse(List<Prices> response) {
                dataToUpdate = response;
                updateData();
            }
            @Override
            public void handleFault(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).execute();
    }
```

updateData  метод который запускает Timer.

```java
void updateData(){
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(repeatedTask,0,  5 * 1000);
}
```

Метод который обновляет данные

```java
void updatePrices() {
        
                updateBackgroundTask.getTickerDataForUpdate(updatePricesModels.get(i).getCurrencies(), new RequestTickerAsyncTaskCallBack<Prices>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleResponse(List<Prices> response) {
                        prices = response;
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();       
                        pid = false;
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void handleFault(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "e.getMessage()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Если вызвать этот метод без таймера все работает, но только при запуске и adapter.notifyDataSetChanged тоже работает, но если вызвать этот метод внутри Таймера данные обновляются(скачиваются) но adapter не обновляется.

В начале я объявил Timer и  TimerTask.

```java
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask repeatedTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!pid){
                pid = true;
                updatePrices();
            }
        }
    };
```

Подскажите пожалуйста насколько правильно я все делаю? Как мне заставить адаптер обновляться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я могу ошибиться, потому как плохо понимаю как работает TimerTask. Но мне кажется что проблема ваша в том, что ваша таска выполняется на рабочем потоке и по завершению таски вы пытаетесь обновить из рабочего потока ваш адаптер. А в Android обновлять UI запрещено с любого потока кроме UI потока (он же MainThread).